# adding new rows and values in R based on certain conditions

Tags: r

I have some time series data by quarter, which are based on actuals.

Let's say it looks something like this.

```
df_actuals <- tibble(year=c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020),
             quarter=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
             value=c(10, 12, 10, 8, 9, 17, 11, 14, 15)
             )
```

Then I also have some projections, which are growth rates, that cover the same time period as well as into the future.

```
df_projections <- tibble(year=c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
                      annual_growth=c(.026, .031, .017, .019))
```

I want a dataframe that covers 2018-2021 at the year level using actuals from df_actuals for years with all 4 quarters of values. For any years with only some or no quarters of actual data, it instead applies the projected growth_rates from df_projections to calculate projected values through the final year of projections (which is currently 2021 but will eventually be 2022, 2023, etc.).

The end result would look something like this ideally.

```
year value
2018 10.00
2019 12.75
2020 12.97
2021 13.21
```

Is something like this possible in a straightforward way?

Comment: The expected output should be correct, I think.

The 2020 value should equal the 2019 value * 1.017

The 2021 value should equal the 2020 value * 1.019

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the values are quarterly annualized, so they need to be averaged over the year.

2018 value = (10+12+10+8)/4=10
2019 value = (9+17+11+14)/4=12.75

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. I've added an `NA` to your example data for testing.

```
library(tibble) # Because you use tibble()
library(dplyr)  # One option for calculating annual sums

df_actuals <- tibble(year=c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020),
             quarter=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
             value=c(10, 12, 10, 8, 9, 17, 11, NA, 15)
             )

df_actuals

df_projections <- tibble(year=c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
                      annual_growth=c(.026, .031, .017, .019))

df_projections

# First sum value for each year
ann_act <- summarise(group_by(df_actuals, year), value = sum(value))

# Alternative without add-on packages
ann_act <- aggregate(df_actuals$value, list(year = df_actuals$year), sum)
names(ann_act)[2] <- 'value'

# Merge in growth rates
ann_comb <- merge(ann_act, df_projections)

# Sort to be sure earliest year is first
ann_comb <- ann_comb[order(ann_comb$year), ]

# Project value, finding previous year for each row 
# This is meant to work if some years are missing -- if that is not needed, simpler solution is possible
ann_comb$value_proj <- c(NA, ((1 + ann_comb$annual_growth) * ann_comb$value)[match(ann_comb$year[-1] - 1, ann_comb$year)])

# Select returned value based on whether actual value is available
ann_comb$value_returned <- ifelse(is.na(ann_comb$value), ann_comb$value_proj, ann_comb$value)

ann_comb
```

Results:

```
> ann_comb
  year value annual_growth value_proj value_returned
1 2018    40         0.026         NA          40.00
2 2019    NA         0.031      41.04          41.04
3 2020    15         0.017         NA          15.00
```